# How to get the path of a selected item from a CellTree in GWT

Tags: gwt, path, tree

I have a `CellTree` containing a list of organisations. In the Model, each parent contains a list of a children.
Is there an easy way to get the path of a selected item ? or I have to go with the usual methode by iterating through the tree and lookup by id.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CellTree itself does not have any built-in functionality to retrieve the path for the selected item.
You will have to manually traverse through your tree structure to get the path. You can use a recursive function to retrieve the path. I have done something like that but for a different purpose (programmatically opening nodes in a CellTree).

Answer (score 2):

Not an elegant solution. I fetch the path from the business model instead of the Tree.

```
public void getNodeContainingEntity(EntityBase selectedEntity, TreeNode node){
    if (exit) return;
    int count = node.getChildCount();
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){   
        EntityBase entityChild = (EntityBaseProxy) node.getChildValue(i);           
            if(selectedEntity.getNodeId() == entityChild.getNodeId()){
                    exit = true;
                    currentNode =  node;
            }
            else if(node.isChildOpen(i)){
                TreeNode n = node.setChildOpen(i, true);
                if(n!=null)
                    getNodeContainingEntity(selectedEntity,n);
            }           
    }
}


public List<EntityBaseProxy> getPath(EntityBase selectedEntity){
    exit = false;
    getNodeContainingEntity(selectedEntity,cellTree.getRootTreeNode());
    path.clear();
    path.add(selectedEntity);
    if (null == currentNode) return path;           
        path.add(((EntityBase)currentNode.getValue()));
        while (null != currentNode.getParent() ){
            currentNode  = currentNode.getParent();
            EntityBase entity = (EntityBase)currentNode.getValue();
            if (null != entity) path.add((EntityBaseProxy)currentNode.getValue());  
        }       
    return path;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Well, I hope this does not sound too obvious or misses what you are looking for. But one way to think about it is to start with the selected node and go up (not to start at the root and go down). GWT TreeItems have a getParent() method so keep calling it, adding what you get to a list, until you hit the root (or nothing) and that will give you a reversed path as a list of nodes going up, it is unique, a node can have only one parent, then just reverse the list to get your path going down.

Here is some untested code aimed to be a method of a subclass of TreeItem (otherwise you'd put the node as a parameter to the method, say 'selectedItem' and then substitute selectedItem for this throughout

```
ArrayList getPath(){
    ArrayList path= new ArrayList();  // in reverse ie going up
    path.add(this);
    TreeItem search;

    search=this.getParentItem();

    while (search!=null){
        path.add(search);
        search=search.getParentItem();      
    }

    Collections.reverse(path);  // now coming down from the root

return
        path;   
}
```

Best,
Martin

Comment: the example you gave concerne the Tree widget. I'm actually using the CellTree widget where each node hold an instance of a business model. In my case the parameter is the business model, so I have to browse the Tree recursively to find the corresponding node, then use a similare approach to yours to get the parents. Well...because of performance issues I transfered the path fetching logic to the model it self