# How to walk through a CellTree in GWT

Tags: gwt, recursion, tree

I have a simple question: Is there is any way to walk through a celltree without using `node.setChildOpen(i, true)`?

I have this code sample:

```
public void find(TreeNode node) {
    for (int i = 0; i < node.getChildCount(); i++) {
        if (!node.isChildLeaf(i)) {
            find(node.setChildOpen(i, true));
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

**EDIT**

I posted the complete code here
[How to get the path of a selected item from a CellTree in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904624/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-selected-item-from-a-celltree-in-gwt/9706439#9706439)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to use recursion to traverse through the `CellTree` Nodes.

Comment: I agree that I have to use recursion, my code sample illustrate that, but do I have to open every node I come across ?

Comment: Unfortunately you have to use ``setChildOpen()`` to retrieve the child node (you also have to open it). Can you elaborate on what you want to achieve. Maybe there is an alternative solution not using the CellTree API.

Comment: Well, I'am basicaly looking to retrieve the path of a selected item in a cellTree. So I look for the node containing that object and then I just get the node's parent until I reach the root. But I just realized that the opening of the node is a normal behavior because the CellTree is using a lazy loading, so a node should be opened in order to fetch its children.

Comment: Yes you are right about lazy loading. Is there a way to calculate the path based on the underlying data? Your underlying data must have some notion of child/parent references. maybe you can use that to evaluate the path to a specific child.